# Sql Query to get the record what has the max id number for each type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in sql server.  It has a pid field used as a primary key and a field called deviceid that has a device name. example:

```
pid  deviceid   field3 field4
1    Device1    test    test
2    Device2    test2   test2
3    Device1    test3   test3
4    Device2    test4   test4
```

For a query, i need select * from the table where the pid is the max per device.
Example result:

```
pid  deviceid   field3  field4
3    Device1    test3   test3
4    Device2    test4   test4
```

Im not sure how do do this.  Any one have any ideas?

The closest i got was:

```
Select MAX(pid) from TheTable Group By deviceid;
```

This works but it only gives me the max pid per device in the results and i need all the field for that record.  Adding in the other fields to the select clause resulted in errors saying that the fields need to be listed in the group by clause...  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from (
       select *,
              row_number() over(partition by deviceid order by pid desc) as rn
       from TheTable
     ) as T
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I agree with @SQL; now that we have CTE this is a clean approach. Note that if you want to retain ties for first, replace `row_number` with `rank`.

Comment: Mikael's solution is great, but it doesn't use a CTE.

Answer (score 3):

You were very close... just needed an additional join to get the rest of the results.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
   TheTable t JOIN
   (
      Select MAX(pid) AS MAXpid 
      from TheTable 
      Group By deviceid
   ) maxt on maxt.MAXpid = t.pid
```

Comment: I think over(partition by deviceid is a better option ?

Comment: Sure, but in this case this solution more closely matches what the OP was attempting, so I thought it would click better than a command he might be unfamiliar with...

Comment: Did you try with Execution plan ?

Comment: 1) I'm not the OP, I don't have the data or schema to test the execution plan.  2) In a test against my own tables, the EPs are similar, with the solution not using Over Partition actually being slightly faster. 3) Performance wasn't the point; it was about the simplest answer.  Please read my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from TheTable t where pid=(select top 1 pid from TheTable
  where deviceid=t.deviceid order by pid desc)
```

By using `select top 1 pid` in the subselect, you can pick any order clause you like, to decide which 1 row to return for each deviceid.  A similar syntax works well in a join:

```
select r.deviceid, r.otherinfo, t.* from RelatedTable r
join TheTable t on t.pid=(select top 1 pid from TheTable
   where deviceid=r.deviceid order by pid desc)
```

Comment: I think  over(partition by deviceid is a better option ?